# Unit testing a Python Azure timer function

Tags: python, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

Azure [provide documentation for unit testing HTTP and Queue Python functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing). This is done by creating a mock [QueueMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.queuemessage?view=azure-python) or [HTTPRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httprequest?view=azure-python). However, there is no documentation for creating a unit test for [Timer functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python).

There is a [TimerRequest class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.timerrequest?view=azure-python), but creating a new instance of it fails with the following error:

```
req = func.TimerRequest()
```

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class TimerRequest with abstract
> methods past_due

What is the correct approach for creating a unit test for a Python Azure timer function?

Comment: can't you just abstract your actual business logic into another routine and the timer-triggered Function is doing nothing else but calling that routine? Then you can also write your unit test against that one. Or what do you want to test about the Timer in specific?

Comment: I could do that but that's a workaround for inability to test the actual function, as is possible for Queue and HTTP trigger types. I want to test the function as it would be called.

Comment: again my question: what do you really want to test? the trimer trigger itself has no inputs (compared to the HTTP or queue-triggered functions)

Comment: It has no inputs but it can run with the attribute past_due set or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me anymore, in the end I created a class with the past_due attribute set to True, and that did the trick:

```python
import unittest
from azure.functions import TimerRequest
from my_func import main

class MockTimer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.past_due = True


class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        timer = MockTimer()
        resp = main(timer)
```